# Update Javascript variable from code behin Thread

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to implement a serverside download process which reports its progress to the client.
I defined a global variable in my .aspx site class:

```
    Public progressStatus As Integer
```

Then a start a new Thread to download the images in a List, which also changes the value of the global variable:

```
    For Each imageUrl In imageFiles
        currentUrlCount = currentUrlCount + 1
        indexOfUrlSplit = imageUrl.LastIndexOf("/")
        localFilename = imageUrl.Substring(indexOfUrlSplit + 1)
        If localFilename <> "" Then
            httpClient.DownloadFile(url, localImage)
            progressStatus = CInt((currentUrlCount / totalUrlCount) * 100)
        End If
    Next
```

I use the SetIntveral Javascript methods to check for the value of the global variable every 2 seconds:

```
    var progStat;
    setInterval(function() {
        progStat = <%=progressStatus%>;
        document.write(progStat + "\n");
    }, 2000);
```

Through debugging I checked that the global Variable in the Code behind is calculated and changed correctly. Anyway, Javascript keeps the initial Value of 0.

I would be glad if someone could help me with that problem!

Thank you very much everybody,

Max

Answer (score 0):

When you use syntax like that:

```
progStat = <%=progressStatus%>;
```

progressStatus value is retrieved once and converted to string when page is rendered. At that time value is 0. It isn't retrieved from server every time you call that script.

It means javascript function rendered on your page looks like:

```
progStat = 0;
```

When you keep calling that function multiple times client-side it does not change as page isn't re-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of an Ajax call to retrieve the value from the server. Use the result from the call together with JQuery and then update the UI